# Dust prevention for home servers

Tags: hosting

I found some posts on here about dealing with dust relating to servers but nothing that specifically addressed my question.

I have several servers at home for research and as you can probably guess they are not cheap.  It is impossible for me to remove 100% of the dust from my home as much as I may try. Does anyone know of any practical solutions to filtering the air that will go into the servers? For instance maybe place some sort of material over the bezel to catch dust particles before they enter?

I realize the ideal home solution would be to have a small room with environmental controls but I'm not there yet.

Thanks!

Comment: READ THE FAQ!!!

Comment: A server in your home is not a professional thing to do. This site is for systems administrators working in a *professional* capacity according to the [faq]. Sorry if it's a bit harsh, but you might do well to take a peek at the rules before you ask your next question.

Comment: @MDMarra I manage two racks of servers in our local data center, plus many other client servers. I think I qualify as professional. I have servers at home for research, scientific and administrative. How many sysadmins or developers do you know that keep rack servers at home because they need the computing power? Not many I bet. I'll remember this when I install my GPU nodes, at home, cheers.

Comment: @PaysonWelch I wasn't saying that you aren't a professional. I was saying that servers in your home do not fall within the definition of professional as defined in the [faq]. It explicitly and clearly states that *anything* in a home environment is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an air filter like the ones used for allergies. A dehumidifier or an air conditioner would help reduce the dust too.